# Pulsing water with PEX tubing?

Tags: plumbing, water, shower, pex

Our home is plumbed with PEX tubing, from what I can tell.  When summer started, the shower started running hotter, so we turned down the shower lower and lower.  But when we reached a certain place on the shower dial, the water began to pulse - almost like a massaging shower head, but much slower.  (In case you're wondering, yes, there is a massaging head, but it is definitely off when this happens.)  If we turn the water up or down from this "goldilocks temperature" (which is of course the most comfortable temperature), the pulsing stops.  Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your shower valve not the pex.  Anything else having a problem?

Comment: City or well supply? What kind of shower valve (eg, is it a temperature- or pressure-balancing value)? Since it started in the summer, maybe your incoming water temperature is higher. You could try turning down the temperature on your water heater (though not too far as you don't want Legionella  bacteria to grow), as this would let you have more flow from the hot side without scalding you. I agree with @DMoore though -- very doubtful this has anything to do with PEX piping.

Comment: City supply.  I'm not sure what type of shower valve - I assume pressure-balancing, since we never get any sort of pressure drop except from the pulse.  I've thought about turning down the water heater - it gets positively scalding.  How cool is too cool?

Comment: Also, thanks for the reassurance that it isn't the PEX.  I've never lived in a home that had anything but copper tubing before, but I watched someone install some PEX just after we bought this house, so I know it can be flexible.

Comment: @ilinamorato see [What temperature should I set my hot water heater to?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/29929/what-temperature-should-i-set-my-hot-water-heater)